# Wrappers in Java

Tags: java

```
public class Test {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

            Integer obj1 = Integer.valueOf(12);
            Integer obj2 = Integer.valueOf("12");

            System.out.println(obj1.intValue() + " " + obj2.intValue());

            Integer obj3 = Integer.valueOf("1010", 2);
            Integer obj4 = Integer.valueOf(1010, 2);//Compile time error.
      }

 }
```

//As `valueOf()` method takes both String and the repective type as argument, but then why 
does last statement shows Compile time error where I am trying to use `valueOf()` method with radix.

Comment: What do you want `Integer.valueOf(1010, 2)` to even do? 1010 already is a number, so it cannot be parsed with a certain radix. It's binary representation is `"1111110010"`. Only strings can be parsed.

Comment: @Erwin, then why does Strings s = Integer.toString(10, 2); works while 10 here is a number also.

Comment: Because `Integer.toString` does not *parse* a string, it converts a number *to* a string. It's the *opposite* of `Integer.valueOf`. So while there is a `Integer.toString(10, 2)`, there is no `Integer.toString("10", 2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Albeit a good question,I don't know why your question was downvoted,it might be so because your comment was not seen by most of them!

The first part is indeed correct as answered by `Jeroen Vannevel`,there is no such overloaded version of `Integer.valueOf()` available in java-library!

The `java.lang.Integer.valueOf(String s, int radix)` method returns an Integer object holding the value extracted from the specified String s when parsed with the radix given by the second argument radix. So,here String is parsed into Integer object!!!

On the other hand,you are talking about `Integer.valueOf(1010, 2)`. **The number 1010 is already an Integer and so it can't be parsed again back to Integer**! Also,if you want BinaryString---simply use `java.lang.Integer.toBinaryString()`. For your satisfaction,if you are still thinking of parsing,then proceed below :-

The solution to end your doubt is

> how will you convert `Integer.valueOf(1010,16)` again into Integer
>   object???? It'll be containing String(hexadecimal representation of `3F2`---see F here)!!!
>   I hope you have got the reason!!!
>   Hence,this was not provided in the java-library.

Answer (score 3):

Because there is no such overload. Read the documentation.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: @Jereon, I know that , but my question was why isn't there is a overloaded method to takes a number without double quotes as first argument in Integer class.